Pytorch model is performing better on the cpu than on the gpu
This has gotten me really baffled. I have got a small pytorch model that I trained on my cpu and it gave me a validation accuracy of about 0.91. It was slow though so I ran it on a google colab gpu and for some reason (the code is identical) the gpu model performs much much worse, getting a validation accuracy of around 0.71, despite running for far more epochs. The only thing I changed about the code is a quick fix to make make it run on the gpu. Any help would be appreciated.
I can't include all of the code but I'll include an example below:
# Train the false colour model
epochs = 5
loss_func = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.AdamW(params = mymodel_false.parameters(), lr = 0.0004)

losses = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i, (input_img, target_img) in enumerate(train_loader_false):
        # Zero the gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        output_img = mymodel_false(input_img)
        loss = loss_func(output_img, target_img)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        losses.append(loss)
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}, Loss: {loss}")```

The gpu model:
# Train the false colour model
device = device = torch.device("cuda")
model = model.to(device)
epochs = 5
loss_func = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.AdamW(params = mymodel_false.parameters(), lr = 0.0004)

losses = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i, (input_img, target_img) in enumerate(train_loader_false):
        # Zero the gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        input_img = input_img.to(device)
        output_img = mymodel_false(input_img)
        target_img = target_img.to(device)
        loss = loss_func(output_img, target_img)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        losses.append(loss)
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}, Loss: {loss}")

As you can see all I am really doing is loading everything onto the gpu memory, the rest of the code is literally copy-pasted. Is there a problem with floating point precision or something like that? I've also tried it with the TPU that colab provides and it seems to suffer from the same problem. I'm running everything on my google drive in case that is relevant.

you seem to be training for 5 epochs only. Are you sure that in only 5 epochs the model has reached convergence?

I've trained the gpu model for 30 epochs as well and it does get incrementally better (think 0.73 instead of 0.71), but still far from the accuracy I get from training the model on my cpu for only 5 epochs.

This is really interesting, I'd love to know the answer on this. Can you detail a bit what your data/dataset/dataloader looks like ? Could you print some sort of checksum of your input images to check wether they are similar in values in both cases  (something like the sum of the pixels maybe) ? - also I don't know if you can train with the same data samples order in both cases to compare -
